# Can not interact with embedded Google Map

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I have used the following simple iframe to embed a Google map on my website. I can not interact with embedded map such as zoom, click, pan etc.

I have also added `sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts"` but no change. It seems working in the following snippet but not on my website

```html
<iframe height="450" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=
!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2543.41275071
!2d51.17525880000005
!3d35.72279246142077!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768
!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x61de87510eccb16!2z2LPZhdin2YjYsSDZvtmE2KfZhiwgVGVocmFuLCBJcmFu
!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1471218824160" 
style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 450px;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was another graphical DIV with relative position on the main layer. I have set `style="pointer-events:none"` on that DIV and done.